# Problem with display data Table using php

Tags: php, html, html-table

I have a issue with my display data into a HTML table from PHP

I get the correct data, but I don't know how to not get for each result the column names.

My PHP code:

```
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    $total_row = $statement->rowCount();
    $output = '';
    if($total_row > 0)
    {
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $output .= '
<table class="table">
 <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Region</th>
      <th scope="col">Level</th>
      <th scope="col">Status</th>
      <th scope="col">BE</th>
      <th scope="col">RP</th>
      <th scope="col">Current Rank</th>
      <th scope="col">Previous Rank</th>
      <th scope="col">Flex Rank</th>
      <th scope="col">Champions Count</th>
      <th scope="col">Skin Count</th>
     <th scope="col">Last Play</th>
     <th scope="col">Price</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
</tr>
<td>'.$row["id"].'</td>
<td>'.$row["region"].'</td>
<td>'.$row["level"].'</td>
<td>'.$row["account_status"].'</td>
<td>'.$row["be"].'</td>
<td>'.$row["rp"].'</td>
<td>'.$row["current_rank"].'</td>
<td>'.$row["previous_rank"].'</td>
<td>'.$row["flex_rank"].'</td>
<td>'.$row["champions_count"].'</td>
<td>'.$row["skins_count"].'</td>
<td>'.$row["last_play"].'</td>
<td>'.$row["price"].'</td>
 ';

        }
    }
    else
    {
        $output = '<h3>No Data Found</h3>';
    }
    echo $output;
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="row filter_data">

        </div>
    </div>
```

The filter_data comes from Ajax.

https://prnt.sc/rd4t3f - Results

I want to receive just in table just information from column and not every time column name

Comment: You're creating a new table in each iteration of your loop. Extract the common parts outside the loop and only create new rows in the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate only for rows

```
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    $total_row = $statement->rowCount();
    $output = '';
    if($total_row > 0)
    {

    $output .= '
        <table class="table">
         <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">ID</th>
              <th scope="col">Region</th>
              <th scope="col">Level</th>
              <th scope="col">Status</th>
              <th scope="col">BE</th>
              <th scope="col">RP</th>
              <th scope="col">Current Rank</th>
              <th scope="col">Previous Rank</th>
              <th scope="col">Flex Rank</th>
              <th scope="col">Champions Count</th>
              <th scope="col">Skin Count</th>
             <th scope="col">Last Play</th>
             <th scope="col">Price</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
        '

        foreach($result as $row)
        {
           $output .= ' <tr>
           <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>
           <td>'.$row["region"].'</td>
           <td>'.$row["level"].'</td>
           <td>'.$row["account_status"].'</td>
           <td>'.$row["be"].'</td>
           <td>'.$row["rp"].'</td>
           <td>'.$row["current_rank"].'</td>
           <td>'.$row["previous_rank"].'</td>
           <td>'.$row["flex_rank"].'</td>
           <td>'.$row["champions_count"].'</td>
           <td>'.$row["skins_count"].'</td>
           <td>'.$row["last_play"].'</td>
           <td>'.$row["price"].'</td>
          </tr>
          ';

         }

     $output .= ' </table>'
}
else
{
    $output = '<h3>No Data Found</h3>';
}
echo $output;
```